# How to send datas from angularjs to php using ionic v1?

Tags: php, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am new to ionic and I prefer to use **ionic v1** instead of **v2 or above**. Now, I downloaded the ionic files through **CLI**. And I installed it on my **drive d:**. And I am starting to make a sample project with blank template. While coding, I am trying to send datas to my php file and it gives me an error of **http://localhost:8100/send.php 404 Not Found**. I try to put my **PHP File** Outside of **www/** folder and inside and still error exist. Why? I already searched a lot of stuffs regarding on this matter but, I don't understand them. Here;s my code:

```
$scope.send = function(){
      $http.post('send.php',{
          'name': $scope.name
      }).then(function(response){
          // msg
      });
}
```

I hope somebody can help me regarding with my issue. Thanks in advance!

By the way, here's my folder structure:

`Drive D > CORDOVA > sample_proj > myapp > www > index.html, send.php`

**PHP**

```
<?php

   if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN'])){
      header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: {$_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN']}");   
      header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true');
      header('Access-Control-Max-Age: 86400') // cache for 1 day
    }

    if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'OPTIONS'){
        if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_METHOD']))
         header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS");

    if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_HEADERS']))
        header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: {$_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_HEADERS']}");
        exit(0);
    }

    $data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
    if(!$data){
      echo "Not called properly";
    }else{
        echo $data->name;
    }


?>
```

Comment: what is address of this angular page? Can't put the `send.php` outside of the web root if you need to access it using $http

Comment: see updated code @charlietfl

Comment: try putting a simple `echo "some text"; exit;` at top of that file and see if you can open it in browser at same address. Curious also if you are running php server ... or perhaps running a node server inside the project

Comment: I am running through node

Comment: I am running on node server sir @charlietfl

Comment: ok...there's the reason. Your node config is not set up for that route and probably not set up to serve compiled php either

Comment: How do I setup properly sir? So that I can post data to php and save to database. Because later on, I will upload it online. @charlietfl

Comment: might be easiest to think of it as 2 projects. One for back end and one for front end. I'm assuming you are used to using php and know how to get a php project running quickly. The only issue you would have is running on a different port locally and would have to implement CORS due to different port origin for the ajax. Not sure what you are running on host....assume it is apache/php?

Comment: @charlietfl yes I am running apache/php. I am new to ionic, a weeks ago

Comment: OK...so what I just said does make sense then. Use whatever LAMP/Wamp/Xamp stack you have to open your php on another port of localhost

Comment: This post will help for the CORS http://stackoverflow.com/a/9866124/1175966. Note I was the last one to edit that answer...have used it a lot myself

Comment: Then what it boils down to is you can use all the node CLI stuff for the front end development....and the php would be normal to you

Comment: So, I will put that code in my `send.php` sir? @charlietfl

Comment: that CORS code...yes. And make sure to call `cors();` function

Comment: Thanks sir! ILL TRY IT RIGTH AWAY! @charlietfl

Comment: By the way, Can I contact you through facebook? @charlietfl

Comment: I never use facebook. I am on this site a lot though

Comment: Still not found sir! @charlietfl

Comment: are you running php server on another port which you should be? Will need full localhost path to make request ....`http://localhost:3000/send.php` for example. Think of it the same as calling a completely different website

Comment: I don't know sir. I am new to ionic and node. @charlietfl , See updated post sir above!

Comment: ok...well you know the node page works....go to wherever you keep other local php stuff you work on and put send.php there..open that in browser and copy the full address to use for the ionaic ajax requests

Comment: @charlietfl I tried to locate my `send.php` through the url. like this: `http://192.168.1.16:8100/send.php`. And It downloaded the `send.php` file and there's a message from my console:  `2Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type application/octet-stream: "http://192.168.1.16:8100/ionic.php".`

Comment: is send.php in same place you use other local php you work on?

Comment: No sir. My other php projects located at `Drive c:/xampp/htdocs/php_projects_here`. While this new one, I install it on `Drive d:/Cordova/sample_proj/myapp/`

Comment: right!! put send.php in xampp! Again...think of this as 2 projects....one for the front end (Ionic/node) and one for back end (php)

Comment: Still not found sir :( @charlietfl I put `send.php inside xampp folder` and `inside htdocs folder`

Comment: It's maybe on my `$http.post` address sir? or not? @charlietfl

Comment: Wait sir! I tried to changed my `$http.post` address from `send.php` to `http://192.168.1.16/send.php` and I got a message! `(index):1 XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://192.168.1.16/send.php. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://192.168.1.16:8100' is therefore not allowed access.`  @charlietfl

Comment: ok...open send.php in browser with only a simple `echo "some text"; exit;` at top . Then copy the whole address `'http://localhost/my_project/send.php` to the `$http`

Comment: ok...that's the CORS message...you dind't call `cors()`

Comment: I already did sir. @charlietfl

Comment: that cors code you posted above looks different than the code i linked to. Shouldn't be echo anything for OPTIONS request and that's why there is an `exit()` for method OPTIONS

Comment: Thank you so much sir! It now works for me!!!!! <3

Comment: cool....the $http is working??

Comment: @charlietfl, Yes sir! Thank you so much!!! I love you!

Comment: do some reading about what CORS is and how it works....will be worth knowing later. Glad it all worked

Comment: Thanks sir! By the way sir. I am planning to make a mobile app and its server is online. Is that possible? I mean, I want to make an online mobile app. So, I also need an online server. Is that okay?

Comment: yes...most mobile apps connect to internet for data

Answer (score 0):

After debugging and asking many questions to @charlietfl. My problem was solved! Thanks to him! As he said, "Think of your projects as a `2 projects (first for your backend (php) and second to your frontend(ionic,etc.))`". I just put my `send.php` file inside `htdocs folder in my xampp folder`and change the `$http addres to : http://192.168.1.16/send.php`. And of course, for it to works perfectly I put the `CORS in it` just see my post! And it solved the problem!